# Please how can i change RichTextBox KeyTab numbering to alphabet numbering?

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

RichTextBox KeyTab numbering look with ToggleNumbering
  like This:

1. KEJBAWGVÖTBG
2. DFÖVGRJTÖIRBG

   1. FIRELIVGURHTG
   2. SVKGNRTÖBGJITRÖ
   3. RESBVGRTDBJHIFG

How can i change it to alphabet numbering like This:

1. KEJBAWGVÖTBG
2. DFÖVGRJTÖIRBG

   a.    FIRELIVGURHTG

   b.    SVKGNRTÖBGJITRÖ

   c.    RESBVGRTDBJHIFG

Comment: Can you provide us some code?

Comment: <RichTextBox Name="RibbonRTF"  BorderThickness="2"  BorderBrush=  "#FF042949"   Padding="5"                                
                                   AcceptsReturn="True" 
                                   AcceptsTab="True"                                                                   
                                 SelectionChanged="RibbonRTF_SelectionChanged"
                                    Margin="0,0,0,10" FontSize="16" >
                     </RichTextBox>

Comment: I Just set  AcceptsReturn="True"  And AcceptsTab="True"

Comment: <RibbonButton  Command="EditingCommands.ToggleNumbering"     SmallImageSource="Images\list-numbers.png" Label="Numbering" KeyTip="Numbering" />